# Get the value of confused Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I got a piece of code like this:

```
var password = eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?"":e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1;};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p;}('9 5$=["\\8\\3\\4\\3\\2\\2\\1\\3\\2\\3\\3\\2\\2\\7\\3\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\3\\1\\3\\2\\2\\2\\1\\3\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\2\\1\\3\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\2\\1\\3\\1\\3\\2\\2"];6 c(){e["\\f\\g\\d\\a\\b"](5$[0])}',17,17,'|x2b|x5d|x5b|x21|_|function|x29|x28|var|x72|x74|O0|x65|window|x61|x6c'.split('|'),0,{}));
```

And I unpacked the following code(except 'var password = '):

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?"":e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1;};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p;}('9 5$=["\\8\\3\\4\\3\\2\\2\\1\\3\\2\\3\\3\\2\\2\\7\\3\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\3\\1\\3\\2\\2\\2\\1\\3\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\2\\1\\3\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\1\\4\\1\\3\\2\\2\\1\\3\\1\\3\\2\\2"];6 c(){e["\\f\\g\\d\\a\\b"](5$[0])}',17,17,'|x2b|x5d|x5b|x21|_|function|x29|x28|var|x72|x74|O0|x65|window|x61|x6c'.split('|'),0,{}));
```

Then I got:

```
var _$ = ["\x28\x5b\x21\x5b\x5d\x5d\x2b\x5b\x5d\x5b\x5b\x5d\x5d\x29\x5b\x2b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x2b\x5b\x2b\x5b\x5d\x5d\x5d\x2b\x5b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x2b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x2b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x5d\x2b\x5b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x2b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x2b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x2b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x2b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x2b\x21\x2b\x5b\x5d\x5d\x2b\x5b\x2b\x5b\x5d\x5d"];

function O0() {
    window["\x61\x6c\x65\x72\x74"](_$[0])
}
```

And after decoding:

```
var _$ = ["([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]"];

function O0() {
    window["alert"](_$[0])
}
```

Now I wonder how the codes execute and what is the value of password ?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The code is obfuscated and intended to permit execution of arbitrary code even if the script text is passed through filters.

The approach is often used for tracking, phishing and other undesirable activities, so I would suggest you don't try running it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is run this code -- not the 'window' stuff, but only the 'decode' part -- and you'll see the solution.

Here are some pointers on decoding:

1. the outer array brackets are a decoy
2. an empty array `[]` evaluates to `0` when used in a calculation such as `+[]`
3. `!0 = 1`
4. `!+0` evaluates to `true` or `1`, `!+1` to `false` or `0` (this surely must be a loophole in Javascript)
5. .. so `!+[]` is simply `1`.
6. `[1]+[1]` is not a valid math sum, so both arrays are converted to strings before being added up.

The above takes care of the numbers. Where does the first character come from? The first part `([![]]+[][[]])` evaluates directly to <strike>a string</strike> two constants, which add together as a string again, and the array index after it picks up a single character.

Comment: as you answer above, that code equals to: var _$ =  "([![]]+[][[]])[+1+ 0+[ 0 ]]+[  1 +  1 +  1 ]+[  1 +  1 +  1 +  1 +  1 +  1 ]+[ 0 ]" ;   And [+1+ 0+[ 0 ]] = [+1+0+[]] = [+1+1] = [2] ? So first part equals to '!' ?

Comment: so ([![]]+[][[]]) = ([!0 ]+[][ 0]) = ([1]+[]) ? Then?

Comment: Ah .. not *exactly*, so it appears. `![]` evaluates directly to `false` (common sense suggests `!0 = true`), and `[][0]` evaluates to `undefined`. 'Adding' these two values is not possible so JS converts them to the next best thing: strings. The parentheses around makes it a single string, so a single character at offset `[10]` can be lifted out.

Comment: em...I'm a little confused. The first part equals to ([![]]+[][0])[+1+ 0+[ 0 ]] = ([!0]+undefined)[+1+1] = ("10")[2] ???

Comment: No, the two parenthesized parts evaluate to `false` and `undefined`; adding them up gives `falseundefined`. The second, bracketed, part, is `[10]`; therefore, this is `"falseundefined"[10]` -- the character `i`.

Comment: thanks for helping. But I wonder why the code var _$ = ["([![]]+... is executed and finally return the value to $password?